# How to display different feedbackWarnings depending on the input in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, feedback, selectinput, user-feedback

I am trying to create an app where I can have different warnings (using `feedbackWarning` from the package `shinyFeedback`) depending on the user's input.

I saw this [post](https://github.com/merlinoa/shinyFeedback/issues/2) where they were talking about this, but although I added if statements, the warnings don't work as they should.

As you can see in the code below, if you first selection is "second" you will see the message "second", but if you select "third" later the previous message is still there and it doesn't update.

[image: im1]

[image: img2]

Note that **I don't want to control the `selectInput` with `actionButton`s** since I want to show the message before clicking anything else.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(), # include shinyFeedback
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "test", 
    label="Multiple warnings",
    choices = c("One", "Second", "Third")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    if (input$test == "One") {
      feedbackWarning(
        inputId = "test",
        show = input$test == "One",
        text = "First"
      )
    }
    if (input$test == "Second") {
      feedbackWarning(
        inputId = "test",
        show = input$test == "Second",
        text = "Second"
      )
    }else{
      feedbackWarning(
        inputId = "test",
        show = input$test == "Third",
        text = "Third"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware of library([shinyvalidate](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyvalidate/articles/shinyvalidate.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reset the previous warning via `hideFeedback`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(), # include shinyFeedback
  selectInput(
    inputId = "test", 
    label="Multiple warnings",
    choices = c("One", "Second", "Third")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    hideFeedback("test")
    my_text <- ""
    if(input$test == "Second"){
      my_text <- "Second text"
    } else if (input$test == "Third"){
      my_text <- "Third text"
    }
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "test",
      show = input$test == "Second" || input$test == "Third",
      text = my_text
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Although this solution is not suitable if you want to put different messages rather than the choices from `input$text`. What if you want to put sentences? I tried this but it doesn't work. (see next reply)

Comment: ```observeEvent(input$test, {
    hideFeedback("test")
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "test",
      show = input$test == "One",
      text = "This is the first warning. Hi"
    )
    
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "test",
      show = input$test == "Second",
      text = "This is the second warning. This is different."
    )
    
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "test",
      show = input$test == "Third",
      text = "This is the third warning. This is the last one."
    )
  })```

Comment: @emr2 sure that's possible - please see my edit.