# How do I show 3 different possible feedback warnings depending on 1 user input in Shiny?

Tags: shiny

I want to show a user a feedback warning for the following scenarios:

1. The total number of files uploaded does not equal 23
2. The file type is the wrong format
3. Both 1 and 2.

I tried using `if else` statements but can only get the first one to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  fileInput("site",
            "Upload .json",
            accept = ".json",
            multiple = T),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
  textOutput("validate")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  validateJSON <- reactive({
    json <- input$site
    json$filetype <- file_ext(json$datapath)
    totalFiles <- nrow(json)
    
    if(totalFiles != 23){
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("site",
                                     show = totalFiles != 23,
                                     "Total .json files must equal 23.")
    } else if (json$filetype != "json"){
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("site",
                                     show = json$filetype != "json",
                                     "Wrong file format! .json files only")
    } else if ((totalFiles !=23) & (json$filetype != "json")) {
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("site",
                                     show = (totalFiles != 23) & (json$filetype != "json"),
                                     "Wrong file type - 23 total .json files needed.")
    }
  })
  validateWhenClick <- eventReactive(input$submit, validateJSON())
  output$validate <- renderPrint(validateWhenClick())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please print and check if `json$filetype` is a string.  As it is a vector (when multiple files are selected) you cannot compare it to a string `json`.

Comment: Thank you! `json$filetype` is a character vector. I tried adding `targetFileTypes <- rep("json", 23)` and then changed the string `json` to `targetFileTypes` but still having issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Shiny - it's just the order of your logic. You need to check for the double condition first, not last.

Comment: You need to check `if (A & !B) {...} else if (!A & B) {...} else if (!A & !B) {...} else {...}`. Also, you can define `allsameFiletype <- ifelse(sum(json$filetype %in% "csv") == totalFiles, TRUE, FALSE)` to use in the if else condition.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606303/how-to-display-different-feedbackwarnings-depending-on-the-input-in-shiny) might be useful.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I actually realized that formula after I left work, but the hideFeedback() was something I wasn't sure how to implement. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 validateJSON <- eventReactive(input$site, {
    json <- input$site
    json$filetype <- file_ext(json$datapath)
    totalFiles <- length(json$filetype)
    allsameFiletype <- ifelse(sum(json$filetype %in% "csv") == totalFiles, TRUE, FALSE)

    hideFeedback("site")
    txt <- ""
    if(totalFiles != 2 & allsameFiletype){
      txt <- "total .json files must equal 2."
    } else if (totalFiles == 2 & !allsameFiletype){
      txt <- "Wrong file format! .json files only"
    } else if (totalFiles != 2 & !allsameFiletype) {
      txt <- "Wrong file type and 23 total .json files needed."
    }
    shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("site",
                                   show = (totalFiles != 23) || !allsameFiletype ,
                                   text = txt)
    
  })
```